# Paste the values for each column until the today's date google apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've this table, with some information that are link with other tables, almost all the rows have formulas (you can find on the picture).

I update the information on the other tabs and with the formulas, the values and information are pasted in the rows, but I update day by day, so I need to copy/paste the values until the today's day inside this tabs instead of select the columns, and paste values.

Like is shown on the picture, from day July 2nd (column) I've the formulas, and the days before I've only values, I'd like to have the script pasting the information til the today's day.

Here is the script, that I started to opening the spreadsheet, then going to the tab, taking the range of values.

The dates represents the row 5 where I've the dates and the todaydate represents the today's date.

My problem is to go through each column and paste the values. I'd like to paste the values from column A til the column that have the today's date.

I found this part "**spreadsheet.getRange(' ').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)**" that I think is possible to use to copy/paste the values, but I don't how can I access different columns without using the numbers.

Inside the loop, I take in consideration the dates on the row 5 and compare with the today's date to break it.

```
  var sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("...");
  var ss    = sheet.getSheetByName("Reporting");
  var rows = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dates = rows[5]
    
  var today = new Date();
  var todaydate = today;
  Logger.log(columns)
  
  
  for(var i = 1; i < dates.lenght; i++) {
  if (dates[i]==todaydate)
  break;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to copy only the column for today or all columns starting from `column A` and ending with the column correponding to `today`?

Comment: @ziganotschka, all columns starting at column A til the column where we have the today!!! I was trying to take the columns by number but I dont know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It is important to compare dates correctly

- `new Date()` will give you a date object that has a date AND timestamp, since the timestamp of your dates in the sheet is by default `00:00:000`, you need to take this part out of the comparison.
- For this purpose you can e.g. compare only the day and month with [getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) and [getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)
- Once you find the correct date, use its index for finding the right column
- Your code has some minor mistakes such as indexation - keep in mind that array indices always start with `0`, not with `1`!

**Modified sample:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("...");
  var sheet    = ss.getSheetByName("Reporting");
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  //arrays start with [0] - the 5th row in the sheet corresponds to rows[4]
  var dates = rows[4];
  var column;
  var today = new Date();

  for(var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    if (dates[i].getDate() == today.getDate() && dates[i].getMonth() == today.getMonth() ){
      column = i+1;
      break;
    }
  }
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    //modify "A1" to your actual start range
  sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(), column).copyTo(sheet2.getRange("A1"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much!! It really help, I'll try it, just one more doubt, is possible to copy/paste in the same tab? Just to know it.

Comment: Of course, but you might overwrite your data in this case.

Comment: If is possible, for me is a better option to avoid to create other tab on my worksheet!

Comment: In this case jsut replace `sheet2.getRange("A1")` with `sheet.getRange("A1")`. Sidenote: If what you wanted was replacing formaulas by fix values, you can also use `getValues()...setValues()` instead oc `copyTo()`.

Comment: A doubt, after running, I receive the message "**Exception: The parameters (number,number,number,null) don't match the method signature for**", Unfortunetaly I dont know to fix it and couldnt find a solution

Comment: This sounds like the right column was not found. Are you searching in the correct row that has a valid date object compatible with today's date? You can verify by implementing into the `if` statement `Logger.log(dates[i].getDate())` for example.

Comment: Yeap, I used and I didnt receive output. A question, the way that we store the dates as an object, it makes difference when we use it inside the for loop?

Comment: Yes, you should make sure that the cells where your dates are stored are formated as dates. Othwerwise you need to take additional steps to make the date recognized as such  by the script. In your sheet you seem to have correctly formatted dates in row 5 and strings in row 6. To retrieve row 5 you need to use `rows[4]`.

Comment: Perfect, is already working perfectly!!! I found a mistake that I did it.