# Why is my onChange Trigger executing multiple times instead of one after change.?

Tags: google-apps-script

Why is my OnChange trigger triggering multiple times? I have created this code to generate a pdf and email it. To run it automatically I have created an OnChange trigger. It runs good however executes multiple times. Please help...

```
function emailPoaAsPDF() {

  var ss =SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xEEEiLfil1qfetSwZRhr02Q9uoXvWtCxq22JywTu5mo/edit#gid=1872480652").getSheetByName("POA Temp");

  var email = ss.getRange("a37").getValue();
  var cc_email = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";
  var name = ss.getRange("a34").getValue();
  var sub = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx of "+ name;     
  var body = "Hello "+ name + ","
    + "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

  var url='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xEEEiLfil1qfetSwZRhr02Q9uoXvWtCxq22JywTu5mo/export?';
  var exportOptions =
   'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' +
   '&size=a4' + 
   '&scale=2' + 
   '&top_margin=1' +            
   '&bottom_margin=1' +         
   '&left_margin=1.25' +        
   '&right_margin=1.25' +
   '&portrait=true' + 
   '&fitw=false' + 
   '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + 
   '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + 
   '&fzr=false' + 
   '&gid=1872480652';
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ 
  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, sub, body, {
  htmlBody: body,
  cc: cc_email,
  attachments: [{
    fileName: "xxx for " + ss.getRange("a34").getValue().toString() +".pdf",
    content: response.getBytes(),
    mimeType: "application/pdf"
   }]
  });
  var nameFile = ss.getRange("e7").getValue().toString() + " for " + 
  ss.getRange("a7").getValue().toString() +".pdf"
```

Comment: I think you are making changes too fast and some of them are executed with a delay.

Comment: Everything gets updated all at once

Comment: Then you are might doing multiple changes at once.

Comment: As your code is now, it will run on any change - insert row, change sheet name, edit / delete a cell content, updating certain formulas etc. If this is not what you want - please specify on which kind of change you want to run this code? Only when the cell content of `A37` changes?

Comment: @ziganotschka,
Yes only when A37 changes..
Please help

Comment: @ziganotschka 
Hello there,
I tried the active range thing in all the possible ways but it won't trigger the email at all. can u please help me in a more detailed way? My point is, I want the email & pdf to trigger automatically whenever a new data row is added to a sheet. Waiting for a reply

Answer (score 0):

### To specify that a functionality shall be triggered only if the change is taking place in a specific cell - implement a respective conditional statement

Sample

```js
function emailPoaAsPDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xEEEiLfil1qfetSwZRhr02Q9uoXvWtCxq22JywTu5mo/edit#gid=1872480652").getSheetByName("POA Temp");
  var activeRange = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
  if( activeRange.getA1Notation() == "A37"){
  // execute the rest of the code
  }
}
```

Depending in your situation (e.g. if the value changes due to an `ImportRange` formula), a change of cell `A37` might not necessary make it the active cell.

If that is the case, you would need to take an a bit more complex approach - saving the old value in [Script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) and compare the new against the old value within the conditional statement.

You should also consider either you caould use the `onEdit` trigger instead of `onChange` - this will give you access to the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) `e.range`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57787791/how-to-fix-an-onchange-script-that-worked-perfectly-then-stopped-working-when-t) for a more detailed sample.

Comment: Hello there,
I tried the active range thing in all the possible ways but it won't trigger the email at all. can u please help me in a more detailed way? My point is, I want the email & pdf to trigger automatically whenever a new data row is added to a sheet. Waiting for a reply

Comment: `whenever a new data row is added` is different because then the active range will not be only one cell. Do you mean an already existing row being populated or a new row inserted? Check your true active range by implementing before the `if` statement: `Logger.log(ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getA1Notation());` and see the result.

Comment: A new row will be inserted

Comment: By results I mean: look at the resulting log (View->Executions).

Comment: Hey, I have been trying every possible way... Nothing works. Please tell me this...How do i write this code.. if the value of a cell is more than 0, the OnChange trigger should execute. Please note we aren't changing any values manually..........................Other way that i am thinking of is..... If the timestamp of the new row inserted is equal to now() then execute the trigger....Please tell me how do i write the both.... I would be grateful to you.

Comment: " if the value of a cell is more than 0,": assuming that you mean by this the value in cell A37: `if( ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("A37").getValue() > 0){
  // execute the rest of the code
  }` As for timestamps, it is similar, but you need to implement some more code, see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62791531/paste-the-values-for-each-column-until-the-todays-date-google-apps-scripts/62794295#62794295)